# Recieving error retrieving mail with Imap on Gmail (port 143)

Tags: c#, email, gmail, imap

Hello I am currently using limilabs library to connect to my gmail account. The purpose of the program is to send mail and to receive. On my laptop I can only receive mails but on my friend's pc he can both receive and send. So my question is why can't I receive emails on my laptop?

The program is supposed to download the emails and populate the subject in a listbox and on my friend's laptop it is working but not on mine. I am getting some error with port 143. Here is part of my code. Thank you in advance.

```
   public void ReadMail()
    {
        using (Imap imap = new Imap())
        {
            try
            {
                imap.Connect("imap.gmail.com");  //ConnectSSL for SSL
                imap.Login("xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Log in failed. " + ex.ToString(), "Message",   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Comment: Is the `Imap` class built in or using some library?

Comment: Does Gmail support unsecure mail connections?

Comment: @leppie its an external library, am using mail.dll

Comment: @leppie It appears `IMap` is a class in the limilabs mail library (OP does mention that!) - see [here](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) for limited documentation/examples.

Comment: @Lloyd i assume it does, because it is working on my friends laptop, but not on mine, am thinking it has something to do with port 143 but i am not sure.

Comment: @Bridge: sorry, missed that ;p

Comment: @Bridge: ok the above is supposed to connect to gmail and read my mails, so the same application works fine on my friend's pc, but on mine it is not. am getting an error like no response from server for  <my current ip> : 143

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

I needed to use *ConnectSSL* method, and change the port to 993

Here is the single line of code that needed to be changed:

```
imap.ConnectSSL("imap.gmail.com",993);
```

Comment: You can skip the port as Gmail (and most servers) uses default value: imap.ConnectSSL("imap.gmail.com")

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I know nothing about Limilabs mail library.

Two things come to mind:

- You need to enable IMAP support on your account

(From the [GMail help](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77695))

> Enable IMAP in your Gmail settings
>
> - Sign in to Gmail.
> - Click the gear icon in the upper right, then select Settings.
> - Click Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
> - Select Enable IMAP.
> - Click Save Changes.

- Wrong settings

With regards to actually connecting to IMap, the same help page gives the following settings to use:

> - imap.gmail.com
> - Port: 993
> - Requires SSL:Yes
> - Full Name or Display Name: [your name]
> - Account Name or User Name: your full Gmail address (username@gmail.com). Google Apps users, please enter
>     username@your_domain.com
> - Email address: your full Gmail address (username@gmail.com) Google Apps users, please enter username@your_domain.com
> - Password: your Gmail password